# sveltejs/adapter-auto does not specify getClientAddress

Tags: sveltekit

When I try to get the IP of a user/client, it returns the localhost in `npm run dev` (::1), but raises the error sveltejs/adapter-auto does not specify getClientAddress when deployed to firebase. The full error log is as follows:

```
Error: @sveltejs/adapter-auto does not specify getClientAddress. Please raise an issue
    at event.getClientAddress (file:///workspace/index.js:2507:13)
    at POST (file:///workspace/entries/endpoints/api/signin/_server.ts.js:13:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async render_endpoint (file:///workspace/index.js:221:20)
    at async resolve (file:///workspace/index.js:2740:22)
    at async respond (file:///workspace/index.js:2629:22)
    at async handle (file:///workspace/node_modules/firebase-frameworks/dist/sveltekit/index.js:13:22)
```

Is it possible to get the client ip using auto adapter, or should I switch to a third party logging package?

My logging setup is very simple. This is an example endpoint where I try to get the ip of the client:

```
import { adminAuth, adminDB } from "$lib/server/admin";
import { error, json } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import type { RequestHandler } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { LogEvent } from "$lib/components/LogEngine";

export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request, cookies, getClientAddress }) => {
    // token stuff here
    if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedIdToken.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
        // login stuff here
        **await LogEvent(uid, "Logged in", getClientAddress(), "info");**
        return json({ status: "success" });
    } else {
        // deal with errors
    }
};
```

The `svelte.config.js` is given below:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

I use the experimental firebase webframeworks feature to deploy the app to Firebase hosting; the default adapter works for everything except the `getClientAddress()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got some hints for this one by looking at the source of [svelte-adapter-firebase](https://github.com/jthegedus/svelte-adapter-firebase).

We can patch the request event in hooks.server.ts:

```
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  // Intended for cloud function context 
  if (import.meta.env.PROD) {
    event = {
      ...event,
      getClientAddress() {
        const addresses = event.request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') ?? '';
        if (Array.isArray(addresses)) {
          return addresses.join(',');
        }
        return addresses;
      }
    };
  }
  return resolve(event);
}) satisfies Handle;
```

That will return a comma separated list of addresses that forwarded this request, with the left-most being that of the client. See [Google Cloud Functions docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/headers#x-forwarded-for).

Further investigation into [mapping a firebase event to a sveltekit event](https://github.com/jthegedus/svelte-adapter-firebase/blob/c7a56cb4187b6f4f90aecb212e0b731e78c009ce/src/files/firebase-to-svelte-kit.js#L7) may be useful.